# How do I read and write a date to a text file in C#

Tags: c#

I'm building a program that saves data to a text file and retrieves it again for later use. One of the features the program must have is that it must save dates and times.

So far I am using the following code to read and write these dates and times:

```
//Write dates to text file:
String path = string.Concat(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"\database\bob.txt");
StreamWriter save = new StreamWriter(path);
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
save.WriteLine(time);
save.Dispose();
```

and:

```
//Read data from text file:
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
label.Content = reader.ReadLine();
reader.Dispose();
```

Now, from doing this I can confirm that the date gets saved to the text file but the program doesn't read it into the label. Is there anyway around this were it will read into the label so that I can display the date?

Comment: Have you tried using File.WriteAllText() and File.ReadAllText()?  They are much simpler in this case.

Comment: I was using the text files to save more than one line of data.... but on saying that I could always trim away everything I don't need

Comment: Without knowing what display technology you are using (Winforms, WPF, ASP.NET, etc...) its hard to say, but in Winforms you change the content of a Label by setting the `.Text` property.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said earlier; it's wpf, and I'm being forced to do it wpf

Comment: Let us know how you call the Read Data method. Are you using MVVM? Or just event handling in code behind?

Comment: Executing your read-fragment immediately after your write-fragment, the same date/time, that is written, is read. So check possible error sources: "path" is not pointing to the same file, something else is written after the posted write-fragment. Does "label" refer to the intended ui element?

Comment: ^^Event handling code

Comment: ^^No the code leads to the correct sources

Comment: I've figured out how to do it just using ReadAllText() and trimming away the excess

Answer (score 0):

It is usually better to save an object graph rather than writing the data piecemeal like this.

If you have control over the format (which it appears you do), then I would suggest a JSON or XML format.

This is VB, but easily translatable to C#:

```
'''  JSON, Use NuGet to Install NewtonSoft.Json
Imports Newtonsoft.Json
Imports System.IO

Public Class SomethingIWantToSave

    Public Shared Function Load(byval path As String) As SomethingIWantToSave

        Dim result As SomethingIWantToSave = Nothing
        Dim content As String = String.Empty

        If File.Exists(path) Then
            content = File.ReadAllText(path)
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of SomethingIWantToSave)(content)
        End If

        return result

    End Function



    Public Sub Save(byval path As String)

        Dim content As String = JsonConvert.Serialize(Me)

        File.WriteAllText(path, content)

    End Sub

End Class


Use the class like so:
    ' load existing data
    Dim data As SomethingIWantToSave = SomethingIWantToSave.Load(Path.Combine("c:\yadda", "yadda", "content.json"))

    ' make changes if you like.
    ...

    ' save data back to disk
    data.Save(Path.Combine("c:\yadda", "yadda", "content.json"))
```

A similar technique can be used for XML using the `System.Xml.XmlSerializer` class.